# How can I get my Elastic IP working for my EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I set up an EC2 instance, which went very smoothly, and I can currently access it via the public DNS.

Once I had this working, I requested an Elastic IP, which I then assigned to the instance. This appears to have worked properly, and describing my instances from the command line shows the correct IP assigned to the instance.

However, when trying to access the instance via the IP I'm getting timed out. There's a timeout on ping, and in the browser. Ping also times out if I try to ping the IP from the instance.

So far, I have tried detaching the IP and re-assigning it, I've tried releasing the IP altogether and starting fresh, and I've rebooted the instance, all to no avail.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved. For some inexplicable reason Firefox was caching a previous HTTP response from that IP. Clearing the Firefox cache resolved the issue.

Comment: Why would the ping timeout based on the Firefox cache?

Comment: I guess there is no relation between firefox cache and terminal ping.. Can you explain how the problem was resolved?